# Is there a JavaScript HTML template that supports both null-coalescing ("undefined" safe) and protects from XSS?

Tags: javascript, template-engine, dot.js

I was looking for a JavaScript template engine, and chose [DoT.js](https://github.com/olado/doT) (mostly because it's very [fast](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/356)) but had the following issues

- **Null safe/Undefined safe/null-coalescing**, Just like in Freemarker / VTL, I want to be able to pass foo.bar.foobar and not worry about checking foo, foo.bar and foo.bar.foobar that they are defined 
   e.g. avoid things like

  ```
  {{ var val='';try{ var=foo.bar.foobar }catch(){} }}{{= val}}
  ```

  which I feel bad about, or

  ```
  {{= typeof foo !== 'undefined'?typeof foo.bar!=='undefined'?typeof foo.bar.foobar!=='undefined'?foo.bar.foobar:'foo.bar.foobar is undefined':'foo.bar is undefined':'foo is undefined'}}
  ```

  which I'm not sure if I feel better or worse about
- **I want to have good XSS protection**, and as fast DoT.js are by not using DOM, even with the {{! }} operator, I'm not feeling comfortable that all XSS in the world will be handled by find and replace (e.g. what if the author missed something)

  **Documentation** although it's very fast, it's not that popular (yet), but the sources are so small you can figure out most things by just reading them, but having a good community is a great benefit

Which JavaScript template library answers these two requirements, and is still considered fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/mikesamuel/jquery-jquery-tmpl-proposal [benchmarks](http://mikesamuel.github.com/jquery-jquery-tmpl-proposal/tests/templates-benchmarks.html) well against other template systems and has [contextual autoescaping](https://github.com/mikesamuel/jquery-jquery-tmpl-proposal/blob/master/tests/contextesc-end-to-end-test.js) to prevent XSS.

You can see from the [conformance suite](https://github.com/mikesamuel/jquery-jquery-tmpl-proposal/blob/master/tests/conformance-suite.html#L589) that it coalesces `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

mustache.js - Logic-less {{mustache}} templates with JavaScript.

1)
If the  key exists and has a value of null, undefined, or false, or is an empty list, the block will not be rendered.

2)
All variables are HTML-escaped by default. If you want to render unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}. You can also use & to unescape a variable.

Reference: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Comment: Re 2), HTML escaping is a decent first step, but does not prevent against XSS.  For example, injecting `javascript:doEvil()` into the `href` of a link will not be prevented by this default.